# How do I fix a word at the bottom of a banner image?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

[image: bannerphoto]I am pretty new to all this. I have a banner image and would like to fix a word at the bottom of the banner in the center. I worked with padding and position and text align but it is not responsive so when I widen the page it disappears. I know I am royally screwing up the code so if anyone can teach me how to do this correctly would be much appreciated.

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gSoi.png);
  height: 405px;
  background-position: center
}

#banner {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 46%;
  padding-right: 20%;
  font-family: 'Walt Disney Script', arial;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;

}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="banner">
                <p>Gramberland</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Please edit your question. Add code snippet. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Try adding the file `logo.png` as an attachment to the question, then use the uploaded attachment url inside the `url(.....)` of the snippet, so we will (hopefully) see what your problem is.

Comment: Ok I think I have done what you said.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use position for both parent and its child, to nest the components within each other, here's the result of it (P.S. I had to replace the image with the background, for the demo purposes):

```css
header {
width: 100%;
background-color: red;
/* background-image: url(logo.png); */
height: 405px;
background-position: center;
position: relative;
}


#banner {
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
}

p {
font-family: 'Walt Disney Script', arial;
font-size: 15px;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="banner">
            <p>Gramberland</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
```